# Passing whole dataset to stored procedure in MSSQL 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

How do I pass a dataset object to a stored procedure?  The dataset comprises multiple tables and I'll need to be able to access them from within the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you *can* do this with SQL Server 2008 or newer (at least with a DataTable).  Here are the links:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/10/10138579/passing-dataset-to-stored-procedure.aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters

Comment: Any hope for SQL Server 2005?

Comment: You could hack this by serializing your DataSet to XML (using its `WriteXml` method) and then passing in the XML as a string parameter. This means you'd have to do XML processing within your stored proc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Table valued parameter for passing single table in SQL 2008 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

or

refer to this article and use SQL CLR procedure to pass dataset http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpapiez/archive/2005/09/26/474059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the [article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) from MusiGenesis' answer states

> In SQL Server 2005 and earlier, it is
>   not possible to pass a table variable
>   as a parameter to a stored procedure.
>   When multiple rows of data to SQL
>   Server need to send multiple rows of
>   data to SQL Server, developers either
>   had to send one row at a time or come
>   up with other workarounds to meet
>   requirements. While a VB.Net developer
>   recently informed me that there is a
>   SQLBulkCopy object available in .Net
>   to send multiple rows of data to SQL
>   Server at once, the data still can not
>   be passed to a stored proc.

At the risk of stating obvious here are two more approaches

**Parametrize your processing procedure**

You might re-evaluate if you truly and really need to pass a general table variable. While sometimes this can not be avoided the reason why this is a later addition to the set of features that MS SQL Server has is partially because usually you can get around it by structuring your stored procedures and the flow of your data processing.

If you are able to 'parametrize' your process then you should be able to let stored procedures retrieve full dataset based on a limited number of parameters.

This will make the process less flexible, but it will also make it more controlled, which is not a bad thing (similarly like the database which interfaces with applications only on the level of stored procedures is more robust, this approach also, by limiting the flexibility reduces the number of possible cases and consequently the number of possibly unhandeled cases. read: security holes and general bugs)

**Temp tables**

Besides the above there's always approach with temp tables, which can be more or less complicated, depending on the scope of sharing that you need on the data (sharing can be between db users, app users, connections, processes, etc..).

Nice side effect is that such approach would allow persistence of the process (which bring you closer to having undo, redo and ability to continue interrupted work).